# Is it lawful to charge two prices based on customers' sex?

Tags: discrimination, sri-lanka

Suppose a gym advertises fees for female customers as 7000/- LKR, but 12,000/-LKR for male customers.

Is it okay to make advertisements like that under Sri Lankan law or is it sex discrimination?

If it is okay, then what laws apply?

Comment: Consider that a 100kg man will put more wear and tear on the equipment than a 50kg woman. There may be other reasons why female customers are cheaper than males. For example, males may spend more time  at the gym on average than women. Now if my son joined the gym and the parents paid, asking me to pay more than my wife might very well be illegal.

Comment: Yes that is their argument. But there are men who are less weight than women. I myself is 55Kg. And also , I can see there are women who utilize the gym everyday as me. Don't need to say lies , I was utilizing it everyday. In that case they have to analyze their past usage patterns and then name a price. 
And there are women who are weightier than me. Any legal actions or procedure to make it happen. Just take the median weight of males and compare it with median weight of women won't work there. Still comes under discrimination right which is not reasonable. Any way to take legal lawsuit ?

Comment: An argument can be based on averages. They can say "on average men weigh more; you pay based on the average weight of your gender, not your actual weight". Since it is overall cheaper to get payment based on estimated averages than on difficult to analyse actual usage data, they are fine.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2017, Sri Lanka was a party to a treaty related to discrimination based upon sex, and the UN body charged to monitoring compliance with the treaty was in discussions with the Sri Lankan government regarding multiple issues related to this treaty, although apparently not the one identified in the question (at least, not obviously, although since the treaty is designed to prevent discrimination against women, in particular, it may not regulated isolated instances of discrimination in favor of women).

> Sri Lanka’s record on women’s rights will be examined by the UN
> Committee on the Elimination of Discrimination against Women (CEDAW)
> on 22 February. Sri Lanka has ratified the Convention on the
> Elimination of All Forms of Discrimination against Women and so is
> reviewed regularly by the Committee on how it is implementing the
> Convention.
>
> Among the possible issues for discussion between CEDAW and a
> delegation from the Sri Lankan Government are:
>
> - Amendments to discriminatory laws and policies;
> - Women participation in decision making processes, including law reform;
> - Elimination of stereotypical attitudes towards women and girls; Improving women’s access to justice;
> - Measures taken to prohibit torture, rape, sexual and gender-based violence by public authorities and private individuals;
> - Providing support for marginalized women, such as heads of households, older women, war widows, ex-combatants, women with
>   disabilities and internally displaced women;
> - Recognizing marital rape as a criminal offence;
> - Removing punitive provisions imposed on women who undergo abortion.

Greater depth of analysis on these issues is found [here](https://www.ohchr.org/en/NewsEvents/Pages/DisplayNews.aspx?NewsID=21217&LangID=E).

The [International Labor Organization has been concerned about](https://www.ilo.org/colombo/areasofwork/equality-and-discrimination/lang--en/index.htm) unemployment among women, discrimination against women in the "informal sector", and sexual harassment (to which non-legal [codes of conduct](https://www.ilo.org/wcmsp5/groups/public/---asia/---ro-bangkok/---ilo-colombo/documents/publication/wcms_525537.pdf) have been adopted by companies that want to be seen as progressive).

More recently, activism in Sri Lanka has been focused on LGBT+ rights in addition to the points identified above (see, e.g., [here](https://ilga.org/downloads/stakeholders_report_SriLanka_UPR28.pdf)). A [U.S. Department of State report
for the year 2020](https://www.state.gov/reports/2020-country-reports-on-human-rights-practices/sri-lanka/) also noted that in Sri Lanka:

> The constitution prohibits discrimination, including with respect to
> employment and occupation, on the basis of race, religion, language,
> caste, sex, political opinion, or place of birth. The law does not
> prohibit employment or occupational discrimination on the basis of
> color, sexual orientation or gender identity, age, HIV-positive
> status, or status with regard to other communicable diseases.

As 2021 [summary of women's rights in Sri Lanka](https://wbl.worldbank.org/content/dam/documents/wbl/2021/snapshots/Sri-lanka.pdf) entitled "Women, Business, and The Law" noted that there was no law in Sri Lanka which prohibited discrimination on the basis of sex in the extension of credit (although women also [aren't prohibited from taking out loans](https://www.adb.org/sites/default/files/institutional-document/172710/sri-lanka-country-gender-assessment-update.pdf) or engaging in financial and economic activity).

I didn't find any sources that specifically resolved the issue of whether gender discrimination in pricing by private firms was prohibited by law, but it is fair to say that addressing that issue is [not even on the agenda](https://www.adb.org/sites/default/files/institutional-document/172710/sri-lanka-country-gender-assessment-update.pdf) of people concerned about these issues in Sri Lanka, and I found no positive evidence that this was legally prohibited.